# RSS from MySQL - issue with special characters

Tags: php, mysql, xml, rss, feed

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8');
    DEFINE ('DB_USER', 'root');   
    DEFINE ('DB_PASSWORD', '');   
    DEFINE ('DB_HOST', 'localhost');   
    DEFINE ('DB_NAME', 'rss'); 
    $output  = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
    $output .= '<rss version="2.0">';
    $output .= '<channel>';
    $output .= '<title>Feed Demo</title>';
    $output .= '<description>News Feed from MySQL test.</description>';
    $output .= '<language>de</language>';

    $connection = @mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) or die('-');
    mysql_select_db(DB_NAME) or die ('-');

    $query = "SELECT * FROM entry ORDER BY date DESC";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die ('-');

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        extract($row);
        $output .= '<item>';
            $output .= '<title>' . $title . '</title>';
            $output .= '<description>' . $description . '</description>';
            $output .= '<link>' . $link . '</link>';
            $output .= '<pubDate>' . date("d. F Y, H:i", strtotime($date)) . '</pubDate>';
        $output .= '</item> ';
    } 

   $output .= '</channel>';
   $output .= '</rss>';

    echo($output);
?>
```

Hello!
I'm using the code above to generate a rss-feed from a MySql database. It work's very well, until I add special characters to the entries e.g. :,/,ä,ö,ü,ß,?," and so on.
I get the message

> This page contains the following errors:
>
> error on line 1 at column 377: Encoding error
>   Everything before the row with the special characters is displayed properly.

Comment: Tell your database that you expect UTF-8 strings as you want to have UTF-8 strings to output into XML: http://php.net/mysql_set_charset . Next to that use an XML library to generate the RSS XML, SimpleXML is sufficient in your case: http://php.net/simplexml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [`utf8_encode()`](https://www.php.net/utf8_encode) to encode all your values.

something like:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    extract($row);
    $output .= '<item>';
        $output .= '<title>' . utf8_encode($title) . '</title>';
        $output .= '<description>' . utf8_encode($description) . '</description>';
        $output .= '<link>' . $link . '</link>';
        $output .= '<pubDate>' . date("d. F Y, H:i", strtotime($date)) . '</pubDate>';
    $output .= '</item> ';
}
```

Comment: Always or only if his database table is not UTF-8?

Comment: Well, this function should be called allways that you're using non-utf8 data and you want to output it as utf-8

Comment: Wrong answer and wrong explanation. Works with Latin-1 only, instead set the database client charset. Also wrong with the answer: Text in XML needs encoding otherwise you might inject XML while you don't want to.

Comment: ok @hakre , I didn't knew taht of Latin-1. Thankyou very much for the information. But for the XML encoding, has not been set at the line: `$output  = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';` ?

Comment: No, you only tell that the document is in UTF-8 (this actually is overridden by `header('Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8');` but as it says utf-8 as well, it's superseeded to utf-8. However that is only the *hint*, in concrete all strings have to be utf-8 encoded before being output. So far you *expect* the database returns latin-1 encoded strings that you re-code into utf-8 then. However instead, tell the database driver that you need utf-8 strings and let the database do the re-coding.